# Eigenvalues of the fundamental matrix of Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I am working with a Markov chain with the transition probability matrix being $P$ (square matrix of size $s$ with each row sum being $1$) and the stationary distribution is the row vector $\pi$, i.e., $\pi = \pi P$. Let $I_s$ be the identity matrix of appropriate dimension and let $\mathbf 1$ be the row vector of all $1$s.

My professor told me that $(I_s - P + \mathbf 1^T \pi)$ is the fundamental matrix of the Markov chain and it is non-singular. In particular, if $1 = \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \ldots \geq \lambda_{s}$ are the eigenvalues of $P$, then the eigenvalues of $(I_s - P + \mathbf 1^T \pi)$ are $\lambda_1',\lambda_2', \ldots , \lambda_{s}'$ such that $\lambda_1' = 1$ and $\lambda_k' = 1-\lambda_k$ for $k\neq 1$.

It is easy to see that the eigenvalues of $(I_s - P)$ shall be $\{1-\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^s$ and hence, it is a singular matrix as $\lambda_1 = 1$. It is also clear that $(I_s - P + \mathbf 1^T \pi)$ shall have $1$ as an eigenvalue (by post-multiplying with $\mathbf 1^T$).

However, I can not see why the other eigenvalues of $(I_s - P + \mathbf 1^T \pi)$ shall be $\{1-\lambda_k\}_{k\neq 1}$. Understanding this would also help me understand why the matrix is non-singular. Can someone please explain this?

PS: There are a lot of questions that sound similar on MathSE and MathOverflow  but I did not quite find my answer in any of them.